# Inline method that support translation to sql

Tags: c#, linq

There is a model of a database that contains two entities related to foreign keys, such as

```
class Item
{
  public int ID;
  public string Name;
  public int StatusID;
}
```

and

```
class Status
{
  public int ID;
  public string Name;
}
```

There is my own class

```
class MyClassFormat 
{
  public int ID;
  public string Name;
  public string Status;
}
```

Now I would like to create a method that returns a class of its own, something like that

```
MyClassFormat getTtem(this Item item)
{
  return new MyClassFormat{ID = item.ID, Name = item.Name, Status = item.Statuses.Name}
}
```

The problem is that when I use this method, I get an exception that my method has no supported translation to SQL

Is it possible to create such a method which would be unwrapped its contents instead of calling this method?

**Solved:** Both answers are suitable for solving my problem, but the second one is the one I was looking for, thank you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to write code to reuse in multiple queries, you could factor out an expression like this:

```
static Expression<Func<Item, MyClassFormat>> ItemToClassFormat()
{
    return item => new MyClassFormat 
       {
           ID = item.ID, 
           Name = item.Name, 
           Status = item.Statuses.Name
       }
}
```

This can be used similar to:

```
IQueryable<Item> query = ...;
var selector = ItemToClassFormat();
var results = query.Select(selector).ToList();
```

Comment: I think, OP uses Entity Framework (see error message). So, this should fail too, because LINQ to entities supports only entity types, complex types and primitive types. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dennis it should work. EF allows you to project into non-entity classes (e.g. DTOs) just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
query
    .Select(item => new
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Name = item.Name,
        Status = item.Statuses.Name
    })
    .ToArray()
    .Select(item => new MyClassFormat
    {
        ID = item.ID,
        Name = item.Name,
        Status = item.Status
    });
```

or:

```
query
    .ToArray()
    .Select(item => getTtem(item));
```

The first way is longer to write, but it loads less data from database.
Anyway, you need to materialize query results (`ToArray` method in sample).